# Android JSON Splitting data results by name/type

Tags: android, arrays, json

this is my first attempt at using a JSON file sourced from a local directory on an android device. Now I can parse information fine. My only issue is selecting sub categories i.e if one section contains the Series "x1" I would just want to list the results that contain series "x1". Is there a way to do this? Id like to get the selectors done first before making it look "fancy" :) any help would be great. A snippet of my JSON is below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "value": "value from first field",
    "Series": "x2"
  },
  {
    "Batch": "0001",
    "character": "Orange",
    "Series": "x1",
    "image": "https://.png",
    "name": "Xr122",
    "value": "Figure"
  }
]
```

Now for my code it reads the following:

```
ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
            //Set both values into the listview
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
            fields.add(jsonObject.getString("name") + " - " + jsonObject.getString("value"));
        }
```

I just don't know where to begin when selecting certain factors when searching. If game series equals "x1" then show etc etc. A point in the right direction would be great. I have a list of over 500 results and thought this would be a much quicker way to sort he results instead of writing a new json file also would allow for custom searches. This is my first try with this so any tips would be great.

Comment: I think you may have to parse the whole JSON string and after that you can use the search criteria

Comment: parse into a list of POJOs and then search those.. I don't understand the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this but it may take some time:

```
ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
        //Set both values into the listview
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);

        String series = jsonObject.getString("series");

        if(series.equals("x1")){
                fields.add(jsonObject.getString("name") + " - " + jsonObject.getString("value"));
          }

    }
```

Comment: Well it does work and is quite fast at sorting just text. I am just thinking if I add a whole lot of images to it might be slow. Ill fiddle around with it. Thanks for the advice.